# ¿Cómo puedo ejecutar de forma automática un trigger que actualize?

Tags: sql, sql-server, trigger

Tengo 25.000 `Insert`. Si ejecuto un `trigger AFTER Insert`, por cada `insert` se ejecutará el trigger. Lo que quiero es que sólo después que mi `insert` se haga por completo se ejecute el trigger. Solo después que se inserta la última fila número 25.000 para que me actualize las filas número 2000 a 10.000.

Estuve intentando con `WAITFOR DELAY '00:05:00' -- esperar 5 minutos`. Aquí os dejo el ejemplo de la consulta 1 en trigger.

**Ejemplo:**

```
USE [PS_GameDefs] 

CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[Asignado_Perfecto] 
ON [dbo].[Items] 
AFTER INSERT AS 
BEGIN
    WAITFOR DELAY '00:05:00' -- wait 5 minutos
    UPDATE PS_GameDefs.dbo.Items SET range = 0 WHERE Type =  25 AND TypeID=1 

    UPDATE PS_GameDefs.dbo.Items SET range = 0 WHERE Type =  25 AND TypeID = 2

    UPDATE PS_GameDefs.dbo.Items SET range = 0 WHERE Type =  25 AND TypeID = 3 

    UPDATE PS_GameDefs.dbo.Items SET range = 0 WHERE Type = 25 AND TypeID = 4
END
```

Quiero que se ejecute después de insertar, específicamente la última inserción. Algo como esto:

```
INSERT Tabla VALUES (1,25,3);
INSERT Tabla VALUES (1,25,1);
INSERT Tabla VALUES (1,25,3);
INSERT Tabla VALUES (1,2,3);
INSERT Tabla VALUES (1,40,3);
INSERT Tabla VALUES (1,2,3);
INSERT Tabla VALUES (1,2,3);
INSERT Tabla VALUES (1,2,3);<<------------ ejecutar trigger despues de insert esta fila NOTA son mas de 10000 registros
```

NOTA no puedo cambiar la consulta INSERT asi por ejemplo:

```
INSERT tabla
VALUES
(1,2,3),
(1,25,1),
(2,1,25),
(1,2,3);
```

Ya que como norma de programadores hay que hacer por asi decirlo nuestros programas como para tontos y yo soy medio tonto, asi que si se me olvida colocar o borrar el INSERT o lo hace alguien que no sea yo se le va a volver un ocho.
ya que quien crea las consultas es un programa echo por terceros del cual no poseo codigo fuente necesito de ejecute cuando entre

```
   INSERT Tabla VALUES (1,25,3);
    INSERT Tabla VALUES (1,25,1);
    INSERT Tabla VALUES (1,25,3);
    INSERT Tabla VALUES (1,2,3);
    INSERT Tabla VALUES (1,40,3);
    INSERT Tabla VALUES (1,2,3);
    INSERT Tabla VALUES (1,2,3);
    INSERT Tabla VALUES (1,2,3);<<--- Esta Ultima no las de arriba
```

Ah importante el 1,2,3 puede Variar puede un dia ser (5,5,6) o Infinito por ello quiero que coloque al ultimo registro de la inserción.

Comment: ¿Cómo hacés la inserción de los 25k registros? ¿Es un escript con 25k inserts o tenes otro método?

Comment: Es para algo puntual? Si es así, por qué no ejecutas las dos consultas por separado? Primero la de los insert y cuando termine ejecutas la que tienes como trigger?

Answer (score 1):

Definitivamente, no uses `waitfor delay ...`. Lo único que lograrás es que cada `insert` sea mucho más lento. Porque el trigger seguirá ejecutándose para cada `insert`.

Si lo que deseas es que el trigger se ejecute 1 sola vez después de todos los `insert`, una opción es de juntar todos los `insert` y convertirlos a una sola sentencia `insert`.

Por ejemplo:

```
INSERT Tabla VALUES (1,25,3);
INSERT Tabla VALUES (1,25,1);
INSERT Tabla VALUES (1,25,3);
INSERT Tabla VALUES (1,2,3);
INSERT Tabla VALUES (1,40,3);
INSERT Tabla VALUES (1,2,3);
INSERT Tabla VALUES (1,2,3);
INSERT Tabla VALUES (1,2,3);
```

... se puede convertir a:

```
INSERT Tabla VALUES 
(1,25,3),
(1,25,1),
(1,25,3),
(1,2,3),
(1,40,3),
(1,2,3),
(1,2,3),
(1,2,3);
```

Siendo que se trata de una sola sentencia `insert`, el trigger solo es ejecutada una vez.

Pero, lo más probable es que lo que estás tratando de hacer no debería hacerse con un trigger. Probablemente sería mejor que conviertas el trigger en un stored procedure que puedes ejecutar manualmente después de tus 10.000 inserciones.

**Edición:**

Otra opción es que desabilities el trigger temporalmente con:

```
disable trigger [dbo].[Asignado_Perfecto] on [dbo].[Items];
```

Luego, puedes ejecutar 9.999 de tus `insert` sin que se ejecute el trigger. Luego rehabilitas el trigger:

```
enable trigger [dbo].[Asignado_Perfecto] on [dbo].[Items];
```

Y finalmente, puedes ejecutar el último `insert` para que se ejecute el trigger una vez.

**Solución ideal**

Como mencioné mas arriba, el uso de un trigger no parece apropiado en este caso.

Lo ideal sería que conviertieras el trigger en un stored procedure como el siguiente:

```
create procedure dbo.Asignado_Perfecto as
begin
    update PS_GameDefs.dbo.Items
       set range = 0
     where Type = 25
       and TypeID in (1,2,3,4);
end
```

Con esto, puedes hacer todos los `insert` que quieras, pero luego debes concluir con la ejecución siguiente:

```
exec dbo.Asignado_Perfecto;
```

Comment: Amigo e problema es que son 10.000 osea convertir uno por uno? pufff eso me llevaria un año por ello recurri aqui por que deseo algo mas estadarizado hermano gracias por tu respuesta puede que en otra me sea util pero aqui necesito que cumpla lo que pido, Gracias.

Comment: @Juan: Con un programita, no sería complicado convertir los 10.000 inserts. Por si acaso, agregué otra opción en mi respuesta que envuelve desabilitar el trigger temporalmente. Pero algo no está bien con el diseño del trigger. En fin, espero que puedas resolver tu problema.

Comment: Por lo difícil que es juntar 10000 inserts en uno solo: reemplazar los insert con un espacio o una coma y luego simplemente colocar a mano sólo el primero para la primera línea y de ahí dejar todo.

Comment: Tal y como opina el compañero, lo ideal y mas sano para tu aplicacion es que ejecutes un store procedure desde tu codigo fuente en el momento que creas indicado, un Trigger traeria muchos problemas , y mas aun si la aplicacion la usan multiples usuarios.